# ajax and jQuery chat

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I'm building a PHP chat (similar to the one on badoo.com).\
Here is the thing to check for messages and who is typing.
I send a request per second, it got a little slow.
So, I started searching around and trying to figure out how Facebook pulls out a huge amount of that, without sending so many AJAX requests.
I noted they just send one and it keeps looping, until some changes occur (e.g. a friend gets online, a new message posted...) and then they send another one and so on.

My question is: How can I do that?

Comment: It's called long polling. Google will give you some example code.

Comment: The technology is called long polling, take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code